# how to attach a PDF document (from documents directory) to an email

Tags: iphone, email, pdf-generation

I was wondering how to attach a PDF that I have generated to an email on iPhone/iPad. I have found examples of how to attach a image, but I don't know the mime type for a PDF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
[picker addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:Your attachment file] mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"file name.pdf"];
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The MIME type for a PDF should be `application/pdf`